# replace mutliple characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

[trying to remove one character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOqq2.jpg)

I scraped this data from the web and want to remove all the non-integer characters in the second column so that I can do maths on it.

Is there another way to remove all brackets and comma in one line

Comment: please add code and sample data here instead screen shot.

Comment: afp['pop'] = afp['pop'].str.replace('(','').astype(str)
afp['pop'] = afp['pop'].str.replace(')','').astype(str)
afp['pop'] = afp['pop'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)  ... this is what i was using to remove the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may strip off parentheses and commas using `str.replace` with the character class `[(),]`.  Then, use `to_numeric()` later when you want to work with this text column as numeric data:

```
df['pop'] = df['pop'].str.replace('[(),]+', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you this also: it creates a new column for each element:

```
df['pop1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pop'].str.split(r'\D').str.get(1))
df['pop2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pop'].str.split(r'\D').str.get(2))
df['pop3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pop'].str.split(r'\D').str.get(3))
```

it suggests that you always have the same nbr of element in "pop".
With the same technique you can also create a list of integer in pop column. Depends of how you wanna work on it.
Like this for example:

```
pop4 = []
for i in df['pop']:
    newstr = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789.-e'else ' ') for ch in i)
    listOfNumbers = [float(x) for x in newstr.split()]    
    pop4.append(listOfNumbers)

df['pop4']=pop4
```

[image]

OFC you can int or float...